# MiniProfiler ASP.NET Core - ShouldProfile based on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I have [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) set up in an ASP.NET Core application. Profiling works fine.

However, I only want Admins to be able to profile.

I have the following in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
    options.ShouldProfile = request =>
        request.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
});
```

The problem is, the user identity does not seem to be loaded in that method.
The `User.Identity.Name` property is null, and there are no claims.
My guess is that this call happens before that info is populated?

How can I profile based on the user identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know that according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_IsInRole_System_String_) the `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()` method checks for Claims of type `ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType`.Be sure you have added the role claims.

Here is a working demo you could follow:

1.Register the user with name `a@qq.com` successfully.

2.Generate the role and add the role with claims to the user:

```
public async Task CreateRolesandUsers()
{
    bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    if (!x)
    {
        // first we create Admin role   
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Admin";
        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
         
         //must add the claim,otherwise IsInRole would always be false..
        _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "Admin")).Wait();
    }
    var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
    if (user != null)
    {
        var result1 = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    }
}
```

2.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultUI();

    services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
    {
        options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";
        options.ShouldProfile = request =>
request.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        options.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter();
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();  //be sure add this
    app.UseAuthorization();  

    app.UseMiniProfiler();     //add this before UseEndpoints

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your example I figured that my problem was that I was calling `UseMiniProfiler` before `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization`. Moving it after them fixed it! Thanks.